# Worldpay giving callback failure alerts from purchases made using Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, payment-gateway, worldpay

I launched a store yesterday after thorough (successful) testing, and once live purchases were made, the client received Callback Failure Alerts from Worldpay. The orders didn't make it through to the dashboard, and the client has had to contact the buyers to find out what they ordered. Understandably the clients are stressed about this. I'm using Store 1.6.1 and EE 2.5.2. I'm desperate for a solution asap. Thanks!

**The content of the email from Worldpay is this:**

> Our systems have detected that your callback has failed.
>
> This callback failure means we were unable to pass information
>   to your server about the following transaction:
>
> Transaction ID: 2479208752
>     Cart ID: 8
>     Installation ID: 269411
>
> Error reported: Callback to 
>   http://www.fabulousflowers.biz/index.php?ACT=37&H=5dfcb904f16e766dcd96781647d779f3: 
>   NOT OK, recevied HTTP status: 302
>     Server Reference: mm2imsps4p:callbackFailureEmail-21277:MerchReq-752-82
>
> Also, if you usually return a response page for us to display to the 
>   Shopper
>   within the time allowed (1 minute), this will not have been displayed.
>
> WorldPay will have displayed to the Shopper the response page file
>   (resultY.html or resultC.html) held for your installation on the WorldPay
>   server. This will be your own custom version, if you have supplied one, 
>   or,
>   if not, the WorldPay default version.

Then there are two attachments:

**response.txt:**

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 16:09:02 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: exp_last_visit=1038845343; expires=Fri, 29-Nov-2013 16:09:03 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: exp_last_activity=1354205343; expires=Fri, 29-Nov-2013 16:09:03 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: exp_flash=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A24%3A%22%3Anew%3Astore_payment_error%22%3Bs%3A38%3A%22Invalid+response+from+payment+gateway.%22%3B%7D2fb730b5f1ab336c121b6a75eb8b6a8f; expires=Fri, 30-Nov-2012 16:10:43 GMT; path=/
Location: http://www.fabulousflowers.biz/index.php/store/checkout3
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

and **request.txt:**

POST /index.php?installation=269411&ACT=37&msgType=authResult&H=5dfcb904f16e766dcd96781647d779f3 HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: www.fabulousflowers.biz
Content-Length: 1062
User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 (WorldPay Java HTTP Request Object)

*deleting personal details of buyer which appears here*

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors and the orders aren't showing in the main dashboard?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the actual error code text to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: More details about the exact errors that are received will help with resolving this.

Comment: The main issue is that WorldPay does not like redirects on the response page. Store sends response to the ACT URL which lets Store update the order status (change status to your completed status) and then redirect to your return URL specified in the checkout template with a 302 Redirect. I have seen a similar issue before when the gateway short_name is not set to "worldpay" as a result of having 2 worldpay gateways setup. Can you make sure that your gateway shortname is set to "worldpay"?

Comment: Thank you! The gateway short_name was set to Worldpay. The problem may have been that I had an 'if no orders' redirect which didn't make sense on these pages anyway. I'll let you know if the problem happens again, but I have a feeling this may be the culprit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cant speak for the Worldpay errors but you should be able to see orders even if they weren't successful. In the Control Panel click on Store then scroll down to Orders. The click on the dropdown for "Filter by Order Status" and set it to "Incomplete" which should refresh the Orders page and show you the customers orders.

Comment: That works, thank you! The client is not getting the automated email alerting them of the new order, and I'm assuming the buyer isn't getting their email confirmation either, but at least the client can now see the order and doesn't have to phone the buyer. Thanks!

Comment: If you change the Status from incomplete to whatever status you have setup in the settings to send the email ("New" by Default) it will send the email to the customer. If you can post a screenshot of the error message or have a URL that might help with diagnosing the Worldpay error you are getting.

Comment: I edited the original question and included the errors above. Any help you can offer would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm still getting the callback error. I don't see any other redirects on the template, verified the short name is in fact 'worldpay', and checked to see the callback url on worldpay is correct. Not sure what to do next to fix this.

Comment: Alissa shoot an email to support@exp-resso.com we can then get some more specific site details and should be able to help you get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I've given super admin access to Adrian. Hopefully he can get it fixed.

Comment: The problem has been fixed! I stupidly had a different callback password on worldpay than I did on the Store settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think almost certainly this is an issue with IIS request validation. This is a different cart, but similar issue and the solution should be similar:

http://www.kartris.com/Knowledgebase/Worldpay-callback-issues---302-redirect-Not-OK__k-48.aspx